# What does "Tas" mean?

Tags: vernor-vinge, zones-of-thought, language-explanation, a-deepness-in-the-sky

Page 20 of [*A Deepness in the Sky*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19493):

> "Tas been done often enough afore, dontcha know? Get ‘em when they
> don’t know technology—or haven’t yet rebuilt it,” said Brughel.

What does "Tas" mean?

Comment: Very interestingly TAS is a utensil which is used to drink homemade cold beverage or water in the region of India and Pakistan. [![something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EP4Za.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EP4Za.jpg)
I know it is not the right answer. Just adding it for general knowledge.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see me address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @GuilhermeWooley: As per Valorum's question, can anything be added to this?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I don't think I'm getting an acceptance on this one...

Answer (score 17):

For clarity, this word should probably have had an apostrophe, indicating that the word is a [contraction](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/grammar/contractions) of "*It has*"

> "***It has*** been done often enough before, don't you know. Get them when
>   they do not know technology, or have not yet rebuilt it"

Comment: *It has* --> *'T 'as* --> *Tas*

Comment: So it's the present perfect tense of *'tis*.

Comment: Depending on the context from the previous sentence, it could be "that's" too.

Comment: I read this book recently and I read it as "that's"